# Scrape follow link with different scraper

Tags: python, scrapy

I am scraping a web page with Scrapy. I wrote my spider and it works just fine, it scrapes a list of Items on a page (let's call it this the Main page). 
In the Main page every Item I consider has a link that leads to the detail Item page (let's call it this way) where detailed information about every item is found.

Now I want to scrape the details pages too, but the spider would be different, there are different information to be found in different places. Is it possible to tell scrapy to look for links in a particular place and then scrape those pages linked with another spider I am going to define?

I hope my explanation was clear enough. Thanks

Comment: You mean different spiders are needed? (different domain, different settings etc.) or would different callbacks be sufficient (different selectors, different items) You can define many different callbacks within the same spider, and also use different domains aswell

Comment: @pault. what you said is interesting, can you make an example of how I can do that? I am a scrapy newbie.

Comment: I added an answer with the basic principle of having multiple callback for different pages within the same spider

Answer (score 0):

You can define the place to scrape by using BeautifulSoup. I have tried to use BeautifulSoup to write a spider program which specify which part you are going to look for together with Urllib. I think this would be a useful [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SFas42HBtMg) for you. I wrote my own based on this. Hope it could help

Answer (score 0):

Identify the pattern first, then write the scraper for each pattern and then depending upon the link you are tracing use the relevant scraper function.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on my earlier comment, here's a sample spider that has 2 callbacks:

- `parse()` would contain the logic you already have for the "main" page, yielding items from the main page, and also yielding fetch requests for the detail page for each item
- `parse_detail_page()` would have a different scraping logic, with other selectors,
  and yielding another class of Items

:

```
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.http import Request
#import urlparse

# items are usually defined in yourproject.items.py
# from yourproject.items import BasicPageItem, DetailPageItem
# I'm defining them here only to illustrate
from scrapy.item import Item

class MainPageItem(Item):
    url = Field()
    name = Field()
    description = Field()

class DetailPageItem(Item):
    url = Field()
    title = Field()
    long_description = Field()
    image = Field()

class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = 'example.com'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    start_urls = [
        'http://www.example.com/1.html',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

        for i in hxs.select('//selector/for/items').extract():
            item = MainPageItem()
            #item["url"] = item_url
            #item["name"] = item_page
            #item["description"] = item_description
            yield item

            # each item on Main page has a link
            # so yield a Request for each one
            # and tell Scrapy to parse it within another callback
            #item_url = urlparse.urljoin(response.url, item_url)
            yield Request(item_url, callback=self.parse_detail_page)

    def parse_detail_page(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

        item = DetailPageItem()
        item["url"] = response.url
        #item["title"] = title
        #item["long_description"] = long_description
        #item["image"] = image
        yield item
```